# What function event should i use when to define when the seleted tab has changed?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dijit.layout.TabContainer , i didnt find in the documentation an event like "onTabChange"
I want to indentify when a tab is seleted and which tab is selected.
How can i achieve this? thnak you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a `selectChild` event.

```
dojo.subscribe("myId-selectChild", function(child){
    console.log("A new child was selected:", child);
});
```

or

```
var tabs = dijit.byId("myId");

dojo.connect(tabs,"selectChild",function(child){
    console.log("called anytime selectChild is");
});
```

More info at http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/layout/TabContainer